# Have a row of buttons, each loading a partial view in a div

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, button, partial-views

Disclaimer: I just started writing actual code so there is propably something obvious i am missing

So, I have four buttons in a page. Below them is an empty div and i want each button to load a different partial view into the div when pressed.

I have already tried every result of googling "have a button render a partial view when clicked" with no result

This is my Index

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "FnB";
}

<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="button" id="addStudentBTN" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Προσθηκη Μαθητη</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="button" id="searchIdBTN" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ">Αναζητηση βαση ID</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="button" id="searchClassBTN" class="btn btn-info btn-lg " data->Αναζητηση βαση Τμηματος</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="button" id="deleteStudentBTN" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg ">Διαγραφη Μαθητη</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="partialBox">
</div>
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/addBTN.js"></script>
}
```

This is the partial

```
@model AkmiFnBCRM.Models.StudentModel




@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Classroom, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Classroom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Classroom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Spesilization, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Spesilization, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Spesilization, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Προσθήκη" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

This is the controller

```
public ActionResult AddStudent()
        {
            return PartialView("AddStudent");
        }
```

And finally here is the last script i tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addStudentBTN").click(function () {
        $('#partialBox').load("/FnB/AddStudent");
    });
});
```

The problem is that no matter what i try the click is never registered(tried alerts before and after the .click()) and even with the .load being in the .ready nothing happens

**Edit** 
the button names were a bit f**ky, fixed them and the script but it still will not load.

Comment: Your Id on your button is misspelled. Missing a 't'.
Also I couldn't get your take on documentReady to run. Try    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#addStudentBTN').click(function () {
        //Your stuff
    });
}). Here is a fiddle you can try: https://jsfiddle.net/wmn76h45/3/

Comment: The script thing was a bad past. As for the buttons i fixed them. It now gets in the onclick() but no loading

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Misspelled Id in your button.
2. DocumentReady looked a bit off.

I tested this and it worked.

```
<div>
        <button type="button" id="addStudentBTN" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"> Try me</button>
        <div id="test">
        Hooray
        </div>
    </div>
```

With this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#addStudentBTN').click(function () {
        $("#test").toggle('hidden');
    });
})
```

Here is the fiddle I tried: [jsfiddle.net/wmn76h45/3](http://jsfiddle.net/wmn76h45/3)

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE:**

Example of an Ajax call to go through backend to fetch partial content:

```
$.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: '@Url.Action("addStudent")',  
            data: '{stuff: 'someStuff'}',  
            dataType: "json",  
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
            success: function (result) {    
                $('#myPartial').html(result); 
            },  
            error: function () {  
                alert("Nope");  
            }  
        });
```

Then you can just have an Action-Method like normally to deliver your Partial.

Comment: Fixed the buttons and script, .load still not working. I will propably end up making different divs with each buttons partial inside and toggling between them, i just wondered if i could us only one, clear it if not empty and then load the corresponding view. Thanks though

Comment: You should be able to have one partial and populate it with different contents. If you have a ASP .Net backend, try go through that to load partial content. I'll add an example of an Ajax call you could trigger to fetch.